# Test to see if variable is instance of jQuery.Callbacks

Tags: jquery, callback

Anyone know of an easy way to test a variable to see if it is an object of type jQuery.Callbacks.

Background: I've got some jquery widgets I've created, and they each have events managed using jQuery.Callbacks.  Some of my widgets use other widgets and will pass along the configuration given to itself to the sub-widget, and this includes events.  So if my parent widget initialises an event, I don't want the child widget to initialise it again, or i'll lose any existing subscriptions.

For Example:

```
var notCallbackHandler1='';
var notCallbackHandler2={ add: function(something) { } };
var callbackHandler=$.Callbacks();

function isVariableACallbackHandler(variable) {
    // <-- What goes here?
}

isVariableACallbackHandler(notCallbackHandler1); // Should return false
isVariableACallbackHandler(notCallbackHandler2); // Should return false
isVariableACallbackHandler(callbackHandler); // Should return true
```

Comment: Doesn't `jQuery.Callbacks().has(callback)` do the trick? Just tested in console: `var fun = function() {}; $.Callbacks().add(fun).has(fun); // true`

Comment: That is checking to see if a callback handler has a callback, which is not what I'm looking for.  I will update the original post to add an example of what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can check if the passed argument has a method which is specific for `jQuery.Callbacks()`. Like this for example:

```
var $callbacks = $.Callbacks(),
    $noCallbacks = $('div'),
    checkIfCallbacks = function(callback) {
        var checkFun = 'fireWith';
        return typeof callback[checkFun] == 'function';
    };

checkIfCallbacks($callbacks); // true
checkIfCallbacks($noCallbacks); // false
```

Update: checking for typeof suffices.

**Update:** Here would be an improved version of your code, just don't use for...in loops and avoid jQuery functions if possible if you want better performance.

```
var $callbacksProto = $.Callbacks();

$.isCallbacks = function (object) {
    // first check if we even have an object
    // this can already save a lot of comparison time
    if (typeof object == 'object') {
        var prop, i;

        for (i = 0; i < $callbacksProto.length; i++) {
            prop = $callbacksProto[i];

            // check if the property name of the original $callbacksProto is a function in our object
            // because every $callbacksProto property is a function
            if (typeof object[prop] != 'function') {
                return false;
            }
        }

    } else {
        return false;
    }

    // if no error occurred return true
    return true;
};
```

Comment: True, I did think of doing this and temporarily I am using this idea already, but I wanted to know if there was something simple I was missing, something already available that I just didn't know about.  Also I don't like the fact that it may return a false positive; however unlikely, I may just have a function on the object named fireWith and in that case, it would fail to be useful.

Comment: Well if you create an object with a function named `fireWith` it would get you a false positive for this one of course. But since you know that, you might want to not name function properties of your custom objects `fireWith` ;).

Comment: You're making the assumption that I am going to be the only one using this and that people read documentation, and generally most don't.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up using:

```
var tempCallbacksObject=$.Callbacks();
$.isCallbacks = function (variable) {
    for (var propertyName in tempCallbacksObject) {
        if (variable[propertyName] == undefined) { return false; }
        if ($.type(tempCallbacksObject[propertyName]) != $.type(variable[propertyName])) { return false; }
    }
    return true;
};
```

I created a tempCallbacksObject so that I wouldn't have to keep creating a Callbacks object each time I wanted to compare.  I also compared every member of the callbacks object so that it is much less likely that an object with a member or two with the same name causes a false positive.

I still don't like it though because it requires a loop and that always takes time, especially since it is likely to be used to check each event handler on each widget I create.  Oh well, if someone finally does come up with something better (or an improved version of this) then I've only got the one place to change it.